# Joomla SEO remove index.php through canonical?

Tags: joomla, seo

I've run my Joomla 1.5 site through the Google Webmaster Tools, it's telling me my site has multiple pages with double title-tags.
Here's an example:

```
http://www.example.com/section/page
http://www.example.com/index.php/section/page
```

I'm using the default .htaccess-file from Joomla 1.5, what should I add to prevent Google to see things like this?
Perhaps a canonical-tag, but a rewrite would be mostly loved for, right?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Either will work.

Either:

- An htaccess instruction following the correct logic with a 301 redirect from index.php to clean, or
- A dynamic canonical tag placed on each page template (generally in Joomla this will fix it, as placing the code on one template will (by default) place it on both the / and /index.php pages.